# Chrome Nacl Video Decoder creation crash

Tags: google-nativeclient

I'm trying to create video decoder using Pepper api.
I compiled and ran the pepper example video decoder api (in the sdk) and sample works fine.
I'm trying to create a video decoder of my own but while i'm calling to create function my nacl library is crashing.
I using the following c code:

```
    PPB_VideoDecoder_1_1 tmpdecoder;
    PP_Resource decoderon = 
    tmpdecoder.Create(instance->pp_instance());
```

The crash happened during the call to Create method.

How do i know why this call is crashing? Is there any exception i can somehow see?
(instance is obviously initialized)

Comment: You may want to check [NaCl: three kinds of crash handling](https://docs.google.com/document/d/19qkl5R4lg-AIDf648Ml-gLRq6eZscjvvdMNWkVu2wLk/edit#heading=h.mqlh6pyxd51e) so you would know which could be performance problems and how to handle them. As discussed, using Windows debugging means that all threads in the NaCl process will be stopped every time a thread is created.  This is potentially quite a serious performance problem. Another reason for crashing is when NaCl runs out of stack which usually happens on a thread created with `pthread_create()`.

Comment: Additional reference that you may also visit is [Debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/devguide/devcycle/debugging). This document describes tools and techniques you can use to debug, monitor, and measure your application’s performance.

Comment: Thank you. I don't think it ran out of stack and it is crash even when no debugging process is done...

I'm just wondering if the Pepper call for video decoder creation prints to somewhere why it has been crashed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the crash was calling pepper api in a thread different than main thread